# ANSI C implementation of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management

I am currently trying to learn the C language by implementing a console version of "Conway's Game of Life".
I have a function called 'set_dead_state', which just create creating a 2d array of 0's:

```
void create_game_board(int *dest[], int width, int height) {
  for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    dest[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*width);
    memset(dest[i], 0, width*sizeof(int));
  }
}
```

Setting `width` and `height` to `10`, I loop through the array and print out each `0` as `" - "` using this function:

```
void print_game_board(int* board[], int width, int height) {
  for(int y = 1; y < height+1; y++) {
    for(int x = 1; x < width+1; x++) {
      if(board[y][x] == DEAD)
        printf(" - ");
      else
        printf(" # ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

It outputs as expected:

```
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
memory freed successfully
```

And I free the memory I allocated in the `create_game_board` function using this function:

```
void free_array_memory(int *arr[]) { 
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(*arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) 
    free(arr[i]);
}
```

My question is in regards to my first try at implementing the `create_game_board` function, which looked like this:

```
// This does not work.
void create_game_board(int* dest[], int width, int height) {
  for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    int row[width]; 
    memset(dest, 0, width*sizeof(int));
    dest[i] = row;
  }
}
```

Below is what outputted to the console when I used this version of the function, in addition to the message I get when trying to free memory (width and height are the same values). I would've expected it to work like the one I mentioned at the beginning. Why doesn't this function work?

```
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -           - 
free(): invalid pointer
exited, aborted
```

Comment: Can we see how you called the version of `set_dead_state` that didn't work? It's important to see how the value of `src` that gets passed to the function is determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your earlier implementation, you set the pointers in `src` to the address of the first element of `row`. But - `row` is a variable on the stack, not on the heap; it gets "de-allocated" when the stack is popped (and used by other functions as part of the stack area). You can't `free()` that address.

However, both implementations are problematic:

- A function which "sets state" should not allocate memory; that's surprising (breaks the [principle of least astonishment](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment)). You could call the function `create_game_board()` or something.
- There's no good reason to make `height` different allocations. Just allocate `width*height` elements once, and set `src` elements to point into different points in that region.
- `src` is a poor choice of name for the game board row pointers parameter. It's not the "source" of anything.
- Why does your comment say the board is 10x10 when its size is dynamic?
- Is the board rectangular or square? If it's square, use the same variable name for both the width and the height (e.g. 'dimension' or 'order' or something).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I will improve the names of my functions so that they are more clear. For the name of the array inside of the function, would a better name for it be "dest[]"?